# Failing when trying to filter an object using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a object,

```
$target = $('#tableA tr[data-id="' + elm.id + '"]');  // Collection of tr
```

I also have a array,

```
var fids = $("#tableB tr .New.selected").parent().map(function () { 
  return $(this).data("fid"); // collection of Fids
}).get();
```

Now I want to filter object `$target` (it's a collection of tr) to only get tr where fid = whatever is in `fids`

I can try it for a single digit but not sure how can i do it for an array, This is what I am trying,

```
$target.filter(function() { 
  return $(this).data("fid") == 4  // HERE i want it to filter based on fids array..
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which returns `-1` if an element is not found in an array, or the position of this element in array.

For instance, if an array is `[1, 4, 7]`:

```
var fid = $(this).data("fid");
return [4, 7, 11].indexOf(fid) >= 0;
```

But when using `indexOf()`, if the argument is a string, not a number, and array elements are numbers, they won't get coerced - so you would need to do that explicitely:

```
var fid = $(this).data("fid");
return [4, 7, 11].indexOf(parseInt(fid, 10)) >= 0;
```

It's rather not an issue - you should almost always use `===` instead of `==` anyway.

Comment: thank you, it works but i am not sure why no one up voted you yet :(